# My basement ceiling\ground floor has a "truss" system. How to hang things?

Tags: hanging, truss

It looks like this from what I can see: http://andersontrussnc.com/floor-trusses/

So - obviously I can't be drilling an eye bolt into anything I see here. I've heard people talk about sistering together trusses by laying a doubled up board or 4x4 between them and screwing the eye bolt to that.  But ... that wouldn't be safe to do from the BOTTOM of the truss in the open triangle, right? Wouldn't it have to be attached to the top?

Kind of frustrating - for a home gym looking at a pull up bar, punching bag etc...and I just don't see how it's possible without tearing down a lot of sheetrock?

Comment: Why is it "obvious" that you can't drill for an eye bolt? Your first assumption is flawed. It's just lumber. Hang whatever you like, within reason.

Comment: I see what you mean, grabbing it midspan might not be so good.  Can you move your grab point to a corner?

Answer (score 4):

Truss systems like that have "strongbacks" at intervals--vertically oriented 2x6 lumber that ties the trusses together and shares load among them. For anything under about 500 lbs. I have no concerns except one:

If you suspend a heavy object at a point along the bottom chord that falls in the center of the gap between web connections, the bottom chord could sag over time. This could result in a bulge in the ceiling, but certainly won't damage the truss system. To avoid this, either be sure to hang from at or near the webbing connection, or spread the load to limit weight at each point to around 100 lbs.

Comment: I have hung really heavy loads, bolted a 2x4 on each side of a tji sitting on the bottom cord the heavier the load the longer the 2x4/ 2x6 without any sag over the years. + for watching out for sag.